# How to connect RecyclerView's ViewHolder and the container activity/fragment?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-viewholder

I made the `ViewHolder` itself as its `OnClickListener`:

```java
public class ListItemViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener {
    ...
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        ...
    }
}
```

Now I can handle the click event of list items in the activity/fragment. However, I want to give a "feedback" to the item. For example, the list item contains a `TextView` and a `ProgressBar`, when clicking on it the `ProgressBar` will show up and the `TextView` will hide, and the activity/fragment will do something like an HTTP request. When the request is over, the `ProgressBar` will become invisible while the `TextView` will show up again. How can I inform the list item's `ViewHolder` of this kind of progress?

Answer (score 1):

Simplest way is to pass Activity upon creation like this

```
   public class ListItemViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener {

    Activity mActivity;

   public ListItemViewHolder (Activity activity) {
         mActivity = activity;
    }


    @Override
   public void onClick(View view) {

        }
    }
```

Comment: I don't understand how this solves the question .. could you expand on your suggestion?

Comment: I think this solution is not so good as adding a reference to the ViewHolder in the activity. But what I want is to make the activity communicate with the Adapter instead of directly with the ViewHolder.

Answer (score 0):

Just use the view of the onClick to get the reference. Example:

```
@Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        someText= (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.someTextId);
        someProgressBar= (ProgressBar) view.findViewById(R.id.someProgressBarId);

        someText.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }
```

If you want to be more specific, create an onClickListener for the desired item

```
public void onBindViewHolder(final ViewHolder holder, final int position) {
            final Someobject obj = objectList.get(position);

       holder.vProgressBar.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                   // Do what you want, hide the text or whatever
                }
       });
    ...
}
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: You have to use `view.getRootView()` first